# VBA Outlook to excel via userform

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm having some trouble with a macro that should move from an Outlook userform to Excel. For some reason the evaluate part is not giving the right answer, any ideas?

```html
Private Sub btnOK_Click()

Dim ctrtype As String
Dim client As String
Dim terminal As String
Dim ctr As String
Dim week As String
Dim vMatch As Variant
Dim sformula As String
Dim xlApp As Object, xlBook As Object

ctrtype = ComboBox1.Value
client = ComboBox2.Value
ctr = TextBox1.Value
terminal = ComboBox3.Value
week = ComboBox4.Value


Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\kkovask\Desktop\RsA2015.xlsx")

    xlBook.Sheets(client).Activate

    
  
 sformula = "MATCH(1,(A:A=" & week & ")*(B:B=" & ctrtype & ")*(C:C=""""),0)"
 vMatch = Evaluate(sformula)
If IsNumeric(vMatch) Then MsgBox Range("C" & vMatch).Address Else: MsgBox "Customer has reached their limit"
        
     xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing



End Sub
```

Comment: try `sFormula = "=MATCH(1,(" & client & "!A:A=" & week & ")*(" & client & "!B:B=" & ctrtype & ")*(" & client & "!C:C=""""),0)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the actual formula:

```
 vMatch = xlBook.Sheets(client).Evaluate(sformula)
```

You need to have Excel run the `Evaluate`, but you should use the `Worksheet` form and not the `Application` form, otherwise there's a chance the formula will be evaluated in the context of a different worksheet from the one you're working with.

Comment: the formula works if run as an excel macro and returns the correct result so this might work, shall try, thanks!

Comment: still no luck, always returns "Customer has reached their limit" even though it should not..

Comment: Have you tried adding quotes around the values you're inserting to the formula (you will need those if the values aren't numeric)

Comment: Use `Debug.Print sformula` to output the formula to the Immediate pane.  Can you copy and use that formula in a cell?

Comment: Thanks Tim, indeed, putting double quotes around the variables in sformula helped.